# Is it safe to use va_list in exception-prone code?

Tags: c++

Typical example:

```
void foo(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);

    // might throw, might not.  who knows.
    bar(fmt, args);

    // uh-oh...
    va_end(args);
}
```

Is this a bad idea, i.e. is it uncommon to use `va_list` in c++?  If I wrap `bar` in a try-catch, does that help?  What would be some alternatives?

Comment: IMHO variable length parameter lists are a bad idea. Look at the `iostream` model for a reasonable solution.

Comment: Just wrap it in try/catch and it should be "safe".

Comment: @EdHeal Variable length parameter lists are fine, as long as you implement them using variadic templates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ standard defers to the C standard for the specification of `va_start` et al. The C standard has this to say:

7.15.1p1 ...Each invocation of the va_start and va_copy macros shall be matched by a corresponding invocation of the va_end macro in the same function.

Thus, if you exit the function by any means after calling `va_start` but before `va_end`, your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Yes, wrapping `bar` in a `try/catch` would help.

Comment: This is of course 100% true and I am not advocating writing code which assumes a specific implementation, but I just wanted to throw out there that all of the three implementations I have seen for `va_end` is something along the lines of `ap = (va_list)0;`, i.e., null out the list.  So not calling `va_end` would technically result in UB, but in practice probably not.  Again, not advocating writing incorrect code here, and a sample size of three isn't huge.  The standard has to be specific about how to use a `va_list` and its related functions, but in practice, it probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

The C++ standard defers this to the C standard.

C99 (draft) 7.15.1/1 tells us that:

> Each invocation of the va_start and va_copy macros shall be matched by
>   a corresponding invocation of the va_end macro in the same function.

Thus if `bar` throws, you fail to execute the `va_end` and your program has undefined behavior. If you add a try/catch to make sure that `va_end` is always called as required then you should be fine. But do remember that you can't pass non-PODs as varargs so if you need to handle them, you would need an alternate mechanism anyway.

A more C++-like alternative would probably be insertion operators (`operator<<`) as is seen in the various iostreams provided by the language.

Comment: … or C++11 variadic templates. Then we don’t need the horrible iostream chained operator hack any more.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above it is Undefined behavior by the c standard.
Yet depending on your platform the marco can compile into different things, I see for me for example it just does args = 0; And va_list is a char*; In which case it seems that the end macro isnt doing anything critical. Nothing bad should happen except im not sure who will deallocate the args, but i don't know where they are allocated in the first place.

I don't in any way recommend using this but sometimes crazy things are necessary for supporting legacy code. If you can use a try catch there then by all means do so.