# static analyzer warning while using va_end inside lambda function

Tags: c++, c++17, clang++

Let's say that I write code like this:

```
va_list args;
va_start(args, size);
va_end(args);
```

In this case the static analyzer doesn't have a problem but when I rewrite the code so that I can handle exiting scope with exceptions:

```
va_list args;
auto closeVaList = [](va_list* list) {va_end(*list);};
va_start(args, size);
std::unique_ptr<va_list, decltype(closeVaList)> guard{&args, closeVaList};
```

Clang static analyzer reports:

```
warning: va_end() is called on an uninitialized va_list [clang-analyzer-valist.Uninitialized]
auto closeVaList = [](va_list* list) {va_end(*list);};
                                      ^

note: expanded from macro 'va_end'
#define va_end(ap)          __builtin_va_end(ap)
```

Is this a false report or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There are some gotchas with this, in particular the C standard has this wording: "Each invocation of the va_start and va_copy macros shall be matched by a corresponding invocation of the va_end macro **in the same function**." That lambda trick might not be doable. (The C++ standard refers to the C standard for most of `cstdarg` as far as I can tell.)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731013/is-it-safe-to-use-va-list-in-exception-prone-code